# ContainsTable: noise/stop word giving no results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, containstable, noise-words

Suppose you have the following queries (using PT language):

```
declare @textoPesquisa as nvarchar(200) = 'haiti and florida and à'
if(@textoPesquisa is null or @textoPesquisa='') set @textoPesquisa = '*'

select * from Noticias n    
 left join containstable(NoticiasParaEstatistica, (Titulo), @textoPesquisa, 
                          LANGUAGE N'Portuguese')  s on n.IdNoticia=s.[key]
 where s.[key] is not null

 select * from NoticiasParaEstatistica where contains(titulo, 
       @textoPesquisa,LANGUAGE N'Portuguese')
```

I'm under the impression that `à` is considered a stop word, so the previous queries return no results (due to the fact that I'm using AND). Now, if I turn off the stopword list, everything works fine, but that doesn't look like a good option.

After looking at the docs, I've found the [transform noise words option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/transform-noise-words-server-configuration-option). I've activated it in the server and I've rebuilt the catalog, but I'm still getting 0 results.

Btw, here's table + insert that might be able to reproduce this scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NoticiasParaEstatistica](
   [IdNoticia] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [Titulo] [varchar](400) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NoticiasParaEstatistica] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [IdNoticia] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO NoticiasParaEstatistica (Titulo)
values ('haiti florida à')
```

What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the records you expect to see in the results, or even better provide a script to generate to generate and insert data for table 'Noticias'

Comment: Hello. Well, any simple table will do it. I've added one with only one row...

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. Are you sure you changed config correctly? Is value set to 1? SELECT * FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'transform noise words';

Comment: Hello again. Sorry, small mistake above (in the insert, just add the words). Do notice that I'm using Portuguese and not English. And yes, activation is on (just rechecked by running your query...)

Comment: This should work. Could you also add the script to create the full text index?

Comment: Hello again. Well, i'm creating a simple catalgo without accent sensitivity:

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [CorpoLimpoNoticias] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
AS DEFAULT

Comment: What about the full text index script? Maybe your key index is wrong so the join doesn't work?

Comment: For the fulltext, I'm using the IdNoticia field (which is the id of the "main" noticias table).

Comment: Do you get a result without the join? select * from containstable(NoticiasParaEstatistica, (Titulo), @textoPesquisa, LANGUAGE N'Portuguese')

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can understand the problem: I'm using a logical and on my search and one of the words is not present because it's a stop word
Not sure on why the transform noise words is not working though...

Comment: well, I'm out of ideas for now since I'm not able to reproduce the problem.